# Need help to limit how many tiles and target spawn in this game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got some simple bomberman game from code pen.For my study,i need to limit how many tiles and target.For tiles max 32 and target 7 (tiles grey & target red).
Here the source : codepen.io/Digiben/pen/oGYGrx

I dont understand how the script create the target and tiles with random algoritm.

Thanks for anyone who look this thread.

```js
window.onload = function(){
//Map Kelas
 class Map {
  constructor (nbX, nbY, tileSize){
   this.nbX = nbX;
   this.nbY = nbY;
   this.mapArray = new Array(this.nbX);
   this.tileSize = tileSize;
   this.map = document.getElementById('map');
  }
  init()  {
   console.log('Map size: ' + this.nbX * this.nbY);
   let i = 0;
   let j = 0;
   let bool = null;

   this.map.style.width = (this.tileSize * this.nbX) + 'px';
   this.map.style.height = this.tileSize * this.nbY + 'px';

   for (i = 0; i < this.nbX; i++) {

    this.mapArray[i] = new Array(this.nbY);

    for (j = 0; j < this.nbY; j++) {

     bool = Math.random() >= 0.7 ? true : false;

     if (bool) {
       for (var z = Things.length - 1; i >= 0; i-) {
        Things[i]
       }
     } else if (!bool) {
      this.mapArray[i][j] = 1;
     }
    }
   }
  }

  appendTile(i, j) {
   let tile = document.createElement('div');
   this.map.appendChild(tile);
   tile.style.width = this.tileSize + 'px';
   tile.style.height = this.tileSize + 'px';

   tile.classList.add('tile');
   tile.style.left = (i * this.tileSize) + 'px';
   tile.style.top = (j * this.tileSize) + 'px';
  }

  getMapArray () {
   return this.mapArray;
  }

  getMapSize () {
   return {sizeX: this.nbX, sizeY:this.nbY}
  }
 }
//Create Target
 class Target {
  constructor (map, tileSize) {
   this.mapArray = map.getMapArray();
   this.playerSpace = map.getMapSize();
   this.targetsArray = new Array();
   this.possiblePositionToStartX = new Array();
   this.possiblePositionToStartY = new Array();
   this.tileSize = tileSize;
   this.map = document.getElementById('map');
   this.totalTargets = 0;
  }
  
  getTotalTargets(){
   return this.totalTargets;
  }
//Show Total Target
  showTotalTargets () {
   let totalDiv = document.querySelector('#score strong');
   totalDiv.innerHTML = ' / ' + this.totalTargets;
  }

  showTargets(i, j) {
   let tile = document.createElement('div');
   this.map.appendChild(tile);

   tile.classList.add('target');
   tile.style.width = this.tileSize + 'px';
   tile.style.height = this.tileSize + 'px';

// set attribute to identify the target when we need to remove it
   tile.setAttribute('data-pos', i + ':' +  j );

// positionning and styling
   tile.style.left = (i * this.tileSize) + 'px';
   tile.style.top = (j * this.tileSize) + 'px';
   tile.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   tile.style.opacity = 0.5;
  }
  createTargets() {
//Target looping
   for (var i = 1; i < this.playerSpace.sizeX-1; i++) {
//Maks Target 2D 10x10
    this.targetsArray[i] = new Array();
    if (i == 1) this.targetsArray[i-1] = new Array();
    if (i == 8) this.targetsArray[i+1] = new Array();

    for (var j = 1; j < this.playerSpace.sizeY-1; j++) {

     this.targetsArray[i][j] = 1;
//Target aLgorithm
     
//Player dont Looping On red Zone
      this.possiblePositionToStartX.push(i+1);
      this.possiblePositionToStartY.push(j+1);
//Target Array if 0 to display Win on the End
      this.targetsArray[i][j] = 0;
//Total Targets
      this.totalTargets++;
//Show Target On map
      this.showTargets(i, j);

     }
    }
   }
   //Show Total Targets
   this.showTotalTargets();

  }
  // Start Player
  getPossiblePosToStart() {
   //Random Start PLayer
   let xPos = this.possiblePositionToStartX[Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.possiblePositionToStartX.length))];
   let yPos = this.possiblePositionToStartY[Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.possiblePositionToStartY.length))];

   return {x: xPos, y: yPos}
  }
  //Player Array
  getTargetsArray(){
   return this.targetsArray;
  }
 }

//PLayer CLass
 class Player {
  constructor (mapArray, map, targets, tileSize) {
   this.positionArray = mapArray;
   this.position = {x: 0, y: 0}
   this.playerDiv = document.getElementById('player');
   this.playerDiv.style.left = 0;
   this.playerDiv.style.top = 0;
   this.playerDiv.style.right = 0;
   this.playerDiv.style.bottom = 0;
   this.playerDiv.style.width = tileSize + 'px';
   this.playerDiv.style.height = tileSize + 'px';
   this.playerSpace = map.getMapSize();
   this.playerMap = map.getMapArray();
   this.score = 0;
   this.targetsArray = targets.getTargetsArray();
   this.totalTargets = targets.getTotalTargets();
   this.tileSize = tileSize;
  }
//Record Posisition Player
  recordPosition(mapArray){
   this.positionArray = mapArray;
  }
//Reset Score when Restart The game
  static resetScore() {
   let scoreSpan = document.querySelector('#score span'); scoreSpan.innerHTML = '0';
  }

//Set Palyer 
  setPosition (position){
   this.playerDiv.style.left = (position.x * this.tileSize) + 'px';
   this.playerDiv.style.top = (position.y * this.tileSize) + 'px';
   this.position.x = position.x;
   this.position.y = position.y;
  }

  getPosition() {
   return this.position;
  }
//Limt Map
  moveRight() {
   
   if(this.position.x > this.playerSpace.sizeX-2) return false;
   if(this.positionArray[this.position.x+1][this.position.y] != 0){
    this.position.x++;
    let nb = this.playerDiv.style.left.split('px');
    this.playerDiv.style.left = (parseInt(nb[0]) + this.tileSize) + 'px';
    console.log('Droite | X : ' +  this.playerDiv.style.left);
    console.log(this.position.x + ' : ' + this.position.y);
   } else {
    console.log('Not OK');
   }
  }
  
  moveDown() {
   
   if(this.position.y > this.playerSpace.sizeY-2) return false;
   if(this.positionArray[this.position.x][this.position.y+1] != 0){
    this.position.y++;
    let nb = this.playerDiv.style.top.split('px');
    this.playerDiv.style.top = (parseInt(nb[0]) + this.tileSize) + 'px';
    console.log('Bas | Y : ' +  this.playerDiv.style.top);
    console.log(this.position.x + ' : ' + this.position.y);
   } else {
    console.log('Not OK');
   }
  }
  
  moveLeft() {
   
   if(this.position.x == 0) return false;
   if(this.positionArray[this.position.x-1][this.position.y] != 0){
    this.position.x--;
    let nb = this.playerDiv.style.left.split('px');
    this.playerDiv.style.left = (parseInt(nb[0]) - this.tileSize) + 'px';
    console.log('Gauche | X : ' +  this.playerDiv.style.left);
    console.log(this.position.x + ' : ' + this.position.y);
   } else {
    console.log('Not OK');
   }
  }
  
  moveUp() {
   
   if(this.position.y <= 0) return false;
   if(this.positionArray[this.position.x][this.position.y-1] != 0){
    this.position.y--;
    let nb = this.playerDiv.style.top.split('px');
    this.playerDiv.style.top = (parseInt(nb[0]) - this.tileSize) + 'px';
    console.log('Haut | Y : ' +  this.playerDiv.style.top);
    console.log(this.position.x + ' : ' + this.position.y);
   } else {
    console.log('Not OK');
   }
  }
//Update Score
  updateScore () {
   let scoreDiv = document.querySelector('#score span');
   scoreDiv.innerHTML = this.score;   
   
//Winner Message
   if(this.score == this.totalTargets) document.querySelector ('#win').classList.add('show');
   
   console.log('Score : ' + this.score);
  }
//Update Target Array
  updateTargetsArray (posx, posy){
   this.targetsArray[posx][posy] = 1;
   console.log('Array state : ');
   console.log(this.targetsArray);
  }
//Remove Target
  removeTarget(posx, posy) {

   
   let targetToRemove = document.querySelectorAll('.target');
   let coords = posx + ':' +  posy;
   let attr = '';
//Loop To find Right Target accroding Coordinates Player
   
   for (var i = 0; i< targetToRemove.length; i++) {
    attr = targetToRemove[i].getAttribute('data-pos');
    if(attr == coords) {
     targetToRemove[i].remove();
     //Update Score
     this.score++;
     this.updateScore();
    }
   }

//Remove Html node (Remove Array Target) 
   if(this.targetsArray[posx][posy] == 0){
    this.targetsArray[posx][posy] == 1;
   }

  }
//Plant Bomb
  plantBomb(){
//Make Child Bomb
   let map = document.getElementById('map');
   let bomb = document.createElement('div');
   map.appendChild(bomb);
   bomb.style.width = this.tileSize + 'px';
   bomb.style.height = this.tileSize + 'px';

//Posision Bomb
   bomb.classList.add('bomb');
   bomb.style.left = (this.position.x * this.tileSize) + 'px';
   bomb.style.top = (this.position.y * this.tileSize) + 'px';
//Variables
   var posx = this.position.x;
   var posy = this.position.y;
   var that = this;

   var timer = setInterval(bombTimer, 500, posx, posy, that);
   var iter = 0;
//BombTimer
   function bombTimer() {
    switch (iter) {
     case 1:
      bomb.classList.add('waiting');
      break;
     case 2:
      bomb.classList.add('before');
      bomb.classList.remove('waiting');
      break;
     case 3:
      bomb.classList.add('explode');
      bomb.classList.remove('before');
      break;
     case 4:
      clearInterval(timer);
      bomb.remove();
      that.updateTargetsArray(posx, posy);
      that.removeTarget(posx, posy);
     default:
      break;
    }
    iter++;
   }

  }

 }
//Game Class
 class Game {
  constructor (tileSize, mapX, mapY) {

//Create Map
   var map = new Map(mapX,mapY, tileSize);
   map.init();

//Create Target
   var targets = new Target(map, tileSize);
   targets.createTargets();

//Create PLayer
   var player = new Player(map.getMapArray(), map, targets, tileSize);
//Place The player
   player.setPosition(targets.getPossiblePosToStart());
//Keyboard Events
   document.onkeydown = checkKey;
   function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
     
     player.moveUp();
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
     
     player.moveDown();
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
   
     player.moveLeft();
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
     
     player.moveRight();
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '32') {
     
     player.plantBomb();
    }
   }

  }
//Destroy Game
  static destroy () {

   let targets = document.querySelectorAll('.target');
   let tiles = document.querySelectorAll('.tile');

   Player.resetScore();

   if(tiles){
    targets.forEach(function(element) {
     element.remove();
    });
    tiles.forEach(function(element) {
     element.remove();
    });
   }

  }
 }

 class Session {
  constructor () {
   this.totalTargets = 0;
   this.players = {};
   this.restartBtn = document.querySelector('#restart');
   this.restartBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    Session.restart();
   });
  }

  static restart () {
  
   Game.destroy();
   var game = new Game(25, 10, 10);
  }

 }




 var session = new Session();
 




};
```

```css
#map {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: lightgrey;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

#game {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

#map .tile {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: grey;
    position: absolute;
    outline: 1px solid #eee;
}

#map .target {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    outline: 1px solid #eee;
}

#map #player {
    border-radius: 25%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #222222;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

.bomb {
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.bomb.waiting {
    animation: waiting 2s infinite;
}

.bomb.before {
    animation: before 1s infinite;
}

.bomb.explode {
    animation: explode 1s infinite;
}

#score p, #score span {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline;
}


@keyframes waiting {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.9);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}

@keyframes before {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1.0);
        background: orange;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
        background: red;
    }
}

@keyframes explode {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1.0);
        background: red;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(2);
        background: yellow;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes win {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    10% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    66% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

h4 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
}

p, strong {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#win {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9999999;
    background: rgba(181, 181, 195, 0.1);
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
}

#win p {
    color: red;
    font-size: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -25%);
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px #333;
}

#win.show {
    animation: win 4s ease;
}

#restart {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    outline: #ccc 1px solid;
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.1s ease;
}

#restart:hover {
    background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
           <title>Bomberman</title>
           <link href="bomber.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
           <script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
        <h4>Space bar to plant a bomb / Arrows to move </h4>
        <div id="win"><p>WIN !</p></div>
        <div id="restart"> RESTART </div>
        <div id="score"><p>Score: </p><span>0</span><strong> / 0</strong></div>

        <section id="game">
            <div id="map">
                <div id="player"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
       
       </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understand your question, but I think you're trying to debug the createTargets method in the Targets class. The problem there is an extra closing bracket (`}`) right before the line with `//Show Total Targets`.